# optional parameter in birt report

Tags: parameters, birt

i had working with more optional parameter like country,state,city and i have wrote some script in before open but its not working ...

before open::

```
if (params["productline"].value && params["country"].value)
{
q1=this.queryText = this.queryText + " AND PRODUCTLINE = '" + params["productline"].value +"'"+" and COUNTRY = '" + params["country"].value + "'"+"group by country"; 

reportContext.getDesignHandle().findParameter("state").dropAndClear();
reportContext.getDesignHandle().findParameter("city").dropAndClear();
Packages.java.lang.System.out.println ("Query1:" +q1);  

}
else if (params["productline"].value && params["state"].value)
{

q2=this.queryText = this.queryText + " AND productline = '" + params["productline"].value +"'"+" and state = '" + params["state"].value + "'"+ " group by state";

reportContext.getDesignHandle().findParameter("country").dropAndClear();
reportContext.getDesignHandle().findParameter("city").dropAndClear();

Packages.java.lang.System.out.println ("Query3:" +q2);  
}
else 
{
q3=this.queryText = this.queryText + " AND productline = '" + params["productline"].value +"'"+" and city = '" + params["city"].value + "'"+ " group by city";
Packages.java.lang.System.out.println ("Query3:" +q3);  
reportContext.getDesignHandle().findParameter("state").dropAndClear();
reportContext.getDesignHandle().findParameter("city").dropAndClear();

}
```

Comment: Which block is executing ? or any exception is throwing ?

Comment: only the if condition is working .....

Comment: any idea sir???please am struggling a lot

Comment: whether if block is executing correct when you give values for productline and country ..?

Comment: are you trying to do this http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/31203-optional-parameter/

Comment: yes executing...but if i select productline and state again it entering to country only???

Comment: can you provide your screen shots pls..so tht i can came up with some idea ?

Comment: yes correct that is my thread only but no reply for that ...so am approaching in stackoverflow????

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/jBDDtx5.png ....               http://i.imgur.com/ylPpptA.png

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44136/discussion-between-sundar-g-and-jagan)

Answer (score 1):

if you are having the screenshots provided by the below [link1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqpdF.png) [link2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK1iO.png) then
you have to do a simple logic in your javascript like this
 var rptFlag = ""
 if **counrty** is selected then assign `rptFlag = 'country'`
 if **state** is selected then assign `rptFlag = 'state'`
 if **city** is selected then assign `rptFlag = 'city'`
 pass this as a **rptFlag**  parameter to the report and 
 in **before open**

you have to check like this...

```
if (params["rptFlag"].value=='country')
{

 /* your query  */

}
else if (params["rptFlag"].value=='state')
{

/* your query  */
}
else 
{
/* your query  */

}
```